# Make character face from photo for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I'm new to Unity 3d. I'm trying to create human character with face generated from photo. (to give real face look) I tried [UMA 2](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/uma-2-unity-multipurpose-avatar-35611) plugin, but it does not support changing face. I searched and found ['Avatar Maker UMA'](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/avatar-maker-uma-150931) can do it. Avatar maker UMA has low quality.
Is there any other way or software to create character from photo and use it in Unity 3d? Would appreciate any sources.

Answer (score -1):

For the Unity Engine is quite impossible to generate faces, you should to it in another system but I want to share with you some ideas from the internet:

Can Unity generate faces?
"Yes and No.... Unity has zero support on this feature out of the box, in fact unity has virtually nothing in this regard, it engine that you design. that's what makes it so versatile and malleable. your problem has virtually nothing to with unity its self. in other words unity won't do it for you but it can be done within it.

but is probably possible if your willing to work really hard at it, many things are possible within unity that it does not come with. however generating 3d detailed meshes from a picture is a really daunting task, your basically need to do some edge detect algorithms... Oh god, its... its nightmare. its even harder because you going straight from scratch.... look I strongly suggest you get real good practice in programming and a really good understanding of how the 3ds does that exactly or you will be in the dark on this one.

Unity has a MeshClass that you will need and the webcam texture.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html

you can use that for the actual generation. but as i said, it is an absolute nightmare of a job.

I hope this answer's your question"

But there is a new plugin that maybe can help you, it's called AVATARSDK and can generate 3d faces.